# Allowing parameters after slash with regex (Google Analytics)

Tags: regex, google-analytics, goal-tracking

i have an application form with funnels in google analytics.

For example form is:
/en/private/credit/application/

And thank you page is:
/en/private/credit/application/thank-you/

So the first funnel is added as a regex:
^(/en/private/credit/application/)$

But the form itself may also have parameters. For example:
/en/private/credit/application/?utf8=✓&amount=1500&term=54

How do i add this variant to the first funnel too?

I want dollar sign to be at the end, because of the thank you page after /application/

Answer (score 0):

You can use an optional group:

```
^/en/private/credit/application/([?].*)?$
                                ^^^^^^^^
```

It will allow `?` followed with 0+  other characters other than newline up to the end of the string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kN7iJ9/1).